# ImageMagick: convert.exe crashes sporadically

Tags: windows-vista, imagemagick, image-conversion

I have a few problems while processing my images in my java program. For the processing, i use ImageMagick version 6.7.2-Q16 under Windows Vista.

#### Problem

I was able to isolate the problem to convert.exe, which crashes sporadically while processing specific images. Executing this batch, I was able to reproduce the error:

```
:start
del C:\Users\Marco\Desktop\picture.jpg
C:\Users\Marco\workspace\AFELO\convert.exe C:\Users\Marco\Desktop\Biller\test1.jpg C:\Users\Marco\Desktop\picture.jpg
if exist "C:\Users\Marco\Desktop\picture.jpg" goto start
```

(Note: It can take a few seconds before seeing an error. Like I said, it only happens sporadically)

The error dialog [here](http://test.s2.olefa.com/resources/images/Marco/Screen01.jpg)

The image i used was [test1.jpg](http://test.s2.olefa.com/resources/images/Marco/test1.jpg):

The error log:

```
Signature du problème:
Nom d’événement de problème:    APPCRASH
Nom de l’application:   convert.exe
Version de l’application:   4.0.1.0
Horodatage de l'application:    4e66b7a2
Nom du module par défaut:   CORE_RL_magick_.dll
Version du module par défaut:   4.0.1.0
Horodateur du module par défaut:    4e66b732
Code de l’exception:    c0000005
Décalage de l’exception:    00105d1e
Version du système: 6.0.6000.2.0.0.768.3
Identificateur de paramètres régionaux: 1036
Information supplémentaire n° 1:    bc9d
Information supplémentaire n° 2:    8b65f71b7628f3d47048baa721edae1d
Information supplémentaire n° 3:    ee0c
Information supplémentaire n° 4:    1d853e407026dac42c650ea56d7c2897
```

This is the farthest I was able to debug. I used the `-debug all` flag in hopes that I'd catch the problem, however imagemagick then refuses to show any error at all.

Answer (score 1):

The problem you reported is a transient bug that is fixed in the ImageMagick-6.7.2-4 release.  Download http://www.imagemagick.org/download/binaries/ImageMagick-6.7.2-4-Q16-windows-dll.exe and let us know if you encounter any additional problems.

Comment: @user932879, if you are using 6.7.2-3, and the problem is fixed in ImageMagick-6.7.2-4, you should do less complaining and more downloading. ;)

Comment: I just checked the new version 6.7.2-5 and i have to admit, that the known problem still exists. :(

Answer (score 1):

Even I was struggling today to run this convert command for ImageMagick. But eventually it ran through. I was running like this:

```
Process pr = rt.exec("c:\\ImageMagick-6.7.7-9-Q16-windows\\ImageMagick-6.7.7-9\\convert.exe  abc.png output123.jpg");
```

So it was not executing properly.
Then I realized that I have to give full path to the images and not the way we are executing in the command line, since in the command line, execution images are relative to the path.
So provide the full path to the images as well.

```
Process pr = rt.exec("c:\\ImageMagick-6.7.7-9-Q16-windows\\ImageMagick-6.7.7-9\\convert.exe  c:\\ImageMagick-6.7.7-9-Q16-windows\\ImageMagick-6.7.7-9\\images\\ankur.png c:\\ImageMagick-6.7.7-9-Q16-windows\\ImageMagick-6.7.7-9\\testing\\output123.jpg");
```